# How can I select a folder from a list of folder using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have just started to learn Java. For this reason it is always required to open notepad++ for my editor, Chrome for internet connection and my java program location in HDD. So I want to create a batch file. I want my command prompt always starts from E:\practice_java when I double-click on my batch file.

I also want my batch file will show a list of some folders from where I can choose my required folder.
My code is..

```
     @ECHO OFF

     SET n=^&ECHO

     echo The avilable directories are : %n% echo 1. E:\Practice_Java %n% echo 2. E:\Practice_Javascript %n% echo 3. E:\Practice_Perl %n% echo 4. E:\Batch_File
```

the next part of my code is..

```
    SET /P var=Enter the folder Number or name you start from: 
    IF "%var%" EQU 1 
    (
    start cmd
    cd /D E:
    cd Practice_Java 
    )else(
    ECHO You did not enter name! Bye bye!!)
```

But It is not working

Comment: `"1"` will never be `1`. Try `IF "%var%" == "1"` (btw: you can just `cd /d e:\Practice_Java`)

Comment: ... the `(` has to be on the same line as `if` and spaces are mandatory around `else`: `) else (`

Comment: Type `if /?` into a command prompt window and learn the `if`/`else` syntax; you will notice that spaces are required here: `) else (`...

Comment: Yes, Now it is working. Thanks.